# How to make background of dialog box transparent in Android?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-dialog

I want to make a custom dialog box, this box is like rating & review box, in which I have to show image and half of its background should be invisible. Image should be appear like its half is out of the box.
I am unable to get it.

My sample code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/transparent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/imageOuterLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/ratingMainLayout"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/upperImageLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/lowerImageLayout"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/lowerImageLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/upperImageLayout"/>

        <com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="@drawable/person_calling_img"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/closeRating"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_close"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/upperImageLayout"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/upperImageLayout" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/ratingMainLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageOuterLayout">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/taskerNameRating"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:text="@string/anonymous"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/taskRatingBar"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/taskRatingBar"
            style="@style/ratingBar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:numStars="5"
            android:scaleX="0.8"
            android:scaleY="0.8"
            android:stepSize="1"
            android:theme="@style/ratingBar"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/taskerNameRating" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/taskRatingHeading"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:fontFamily="@font/axiforma_medium"
            android:text="@string/task_rating_heading"
            android:textColor="#333333"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/taskRatingBar"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/taskRatingBar"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/taskRatingBar" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/reviewRowOneLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/reviewRowTwoLayout"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/taskRatingHeading">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/reviewTxt1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext_border"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:text="Good Drive"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/reviewTxt2"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/reviewTxt2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext_border"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:text="Good Conversation"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/reviewTxt1"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/reviewRowTwoLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/reviewRowThreeLayout"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/reviewRowOneLayout">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/reviewTxt3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext_border"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:text="Nice Car"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/reviewTxt4"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/reviewTxt4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext_border"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:text="Arrived Quickly"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/reviewTxt3"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/reviewRowThreeLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/reviewRowFourLayout"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/reviewRowTwoLayout">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/reviewTxt5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext_border"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:text="Good Vehicle"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/reviewTxt6"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/reviewTxt6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext_border"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:text="Good Conversation"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/reviewTxt5"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/reviewRowFourLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/reviewRowThreeLayout">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/reviewTxt7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext_border"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:text="Good Drive"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/reviewTxt8"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/reviewTxt8"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext_border"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:text="Good Conversation"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/reviewTxt7"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/taskRatingEdt"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/reviewRowFourLayout"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/submitTaskRatingBtn"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:hint="Leave a comment if you want..."
            android:padding="13dp"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/submitTaskRatingBtn"
            android:layout_width="170dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/ripple_effect_send_green"
            android:fontFamily="@font/axiforma_semi_bold"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:text="@string/submit"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/light_black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/taskRatingEdt"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

My output is:

[image]

Where I want output like this:

[image]

I want image on dialog box like this, half of its background should be invisible.

Answer (score 2):

//Add thiss line in on create method od dialog class
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);

Answer (score 0):

Sample Kotlin Code

```
class CustomOneDialog : DialogFragment() {


    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {

        val binding = DialogCustomOneBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)

        binding.btnDone.setOnClickListener {
            dialog?.dismiss()
        }

        val dialog = MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(
            requireActivity(),
            R.style.MaterialAlertDialog_CustomBorders
        ).apply {
            setView(binding.root)

            setOnKeyListener { _, keyCode, keyEvent ->
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && keyEvent.action == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    dismiss()
                    true
                } else false
            }

        }.create()

        dialog.getWindow()?.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))

        return dialog
    }

}
```

xml code;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:background="@drawable/dialog_custom_borders"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingStart="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="48dp"
        android:paddingEnd="16dp"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/dialog_congratulations_title"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Headline5"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/dialog_congratulations_summary"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Body1" />

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_done"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="@android:string/ok"
            android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"
            app:shapeAppearance="@style/ShapeAppearance.Capsule" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/appCompatImageView"
        android:layout_width="68dp"
        android:layout_height="68dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-28dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/linearLayout"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/circle_rounded_filled" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Icon Drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:ignore="UnusedResources">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <size
                android:width="34dp"
                android:height="34dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/md_light_green_A700" />
            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="?android:colorBackgroundFloating" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_baseline_done_24"
        android:gravity="center" />
</layer-list>
```

Button

```
<style name="ShapeAppearance.Capsule" parent="ShapeAppearance.MaterialComponents.SmallComponent">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSize">50%</item>
</style>
```